# C 2darray values are changing unexpectedly

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to get make a 2d int array by doing this. I have a string only contains digits and store the digit value in int array's first row. but unexpectedly values in the second row and the third row are changing. Can someone tell me what is the reason for this?
Here is my code

````
void function(){
    char str[] = "123456789";
    int n = strlen(str),k=2;

    int arr[n+k][k+2];
    for(int a=0;a<k+2;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<n+k;b++){
            arr[a][b] = -1;
        }
    }

    for(int c=0;c<n;c++){
        arr[0][c] = str[c]-'0';

    }

    for(int d=0;d<k+2;d++){
        for(int e=0;e<n+k;e++){
            printf("%d ",arr[d][e]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}```

Here is the output
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 -1 -1 

    5 6 7 8 9 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

    9 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

    -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
````

Comment: The first row is 4 (`k+2`) elements long, but you are storing 9 (`n`) elements in the first row, so it is overflowing into the second and third rows.

Answer (score 4):

In all of your `for` loops, you have the indexes of the `arr` variable the wrong way round! Switching over the indexes will fix your code:

```c
void function()
{
    char str[] = "123456789";
    int n = strlen(str), k = 2;

    int arr[n + k][k + 2];
    for (int a = 0; a < k + 2; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < n + k; b++) {
//          arr[a][b] = -1;
            arr[b][a] = -1;
        }
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
//      arr[0][c] = str[c] - '0';
        arr[c][0] = str[c] - '0';
    }
    for (int d = 0; d < k + 2; d++) {
        for (int e = 0; e < n + k; e++) {
//          printf("%d ", arr[d][e]);
            printf("%d ", arr[e][d]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Alternatively (less code change), you can simply declare the `arr` array with its dimensions swapped over. So, in place of:

```c
int arr[n + k][k + 2];
```

use:

```c
int arr[k + 2][n + k];
```

Then you can keep the rest of your code as it is.

Comment: thank you very much guys, I appreciate all the answers!!

Answer (score 1):

You got the rows and columns wrong in declaration

```
void function(){
char str[] = "123456789";
int n = strlen(str),k=2;

int arr[k+2][n+k];
for(int a=0;a<k+2;a++){
    for(int b=0;b<n+k;b++){
        arr[a][b] = -1;
    }
}

for(int c=0;c<n;c++){
    arr[0][c] = str[c]-'0';

}

for(int d=0;d<k+2;d++){
    for(int e=0;e<n+k;e++){
        printf("%d ",arr[d][e]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

This gives you

[image]